# Understanding mount option nodev and its use with USB flash drives

Tags: usb-flash-drive, mount

[mount(8) OS X Manual Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/mount.8.html) describes the `nodev` option:

> Do not interpret character or block special devices on the file
>   system. This option is useful for a server that has file systems
>   containing special devices for architectures other than its own.

That alone, I don't fully understand …

… for me, the more important part of this question – which may help me to understand the option – is:

## Why are USB flash drives mounted with the nodev option?

Example:

```
sh-3.2$ mount
/dev/disk1 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
/dev/disk0s2 on /Volumes/swap (hfs, local, journaled)
/dev/disk0s4 on /Volumes/spare (hfs, local, journaled)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
localhost:/Eiu9XWYlwq4E8x9l_bQTiX on /Volumes/MobileBackups (mtmfs, nosuid, read-only, nobrowse)
/dev/disk3 on /Volumes/gjp22 (zfs, local, journaled, noatime)
/dev/disk3s1 on /opt (zfs, local, journaled, noatime)
/dev/disk6 on /Volumes/zhandy (zfs, local, journaled, noatime)
/dev/disk8s1 on /Volumes/experiment (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled, noowners)
/dev/disk10 on /Volumes/tall (zfs, local, journaled, noatime)
/dev/disk11s2 on /Volumes/LaCie Little Big Disk (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled, noowners)
/dev/disk12 on /Volumes/twoz (zfs, local, journaled, noatime)
Wuala on /Volumes/WualaDrive (osxfusefs, local, nodev, nosuid, synchronous, mounted by gjp22)
/dev/disk14s2 on /Volumes/Time Machine Backups (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled)
```

In that example, the four volumes with `nodev` are:

1. *experiment* – on a USB flash drive
2. *LaCie Little Big Disk* – on a hard disk drive on FireWire 400, this volume includes a Time Machine `Backups.backupdb`
3. *Wuala* – file system integration uses FUSE for OS X
4. *Time Machine Backups*

Loosely speaking, I can understand that 2, 3, and 4 are special. However:

- I can't understand the relevance of `nodev` to a USB flash drive.

### Other references

[Mounting USB disks automatically (How it works)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8159/13260) – Unix and Linux

### Background

Wishing to understand why Time Machine in Lion and Mountain Lion can not back up from USB flash drives. But this question is more generally about the `nodev` option.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `nodev` option tells the system to disallow creating and accessing *device nodes* – the kind of special files that you have in `/dev`.

For example, `/dev/disk0` gives you direct access to all data stored on the first disk without having to go through the higher levels such as the filesystem or the permission-checking code – the *only* permission checked is whether you're allowed to open that specific device node for reading or writing.

This means that if `/dev/disk0` was made world-readable, **any user** could easily read any other user's files on the same disk (if they were not encrypted), by simply reading from `/dev/sda`.

Depending on the OS, `/dev` will usually have many other kinds of device nodes including `/dev/mem` which gives access to the system's entire (physical and/or virtual) memory – although not with systems running a kernel compiled with `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM` (unless *root*).

For this reason, only *root* is usually allowed to create device nodes (for other users, `mknod` will return "Operation not permitted"), and all existing device nodes are kept in a single location (`/dev`) with strict file permissions that do not give normal users read or write access. *(With some exceptions.)*
However, in modern days, anyone could easily bypass the root-only restriction by going to another computer they already have root access to, using it to create some device nodes on a USB drive, setting very open permissions, and connecting that drive to *your* computer.

This is what the `nodev` option prevents – even if somebody creates a world-readable/world-writable device node on their own drive, the OS will refuse to do anything with it because of the `nodev` option used when mounting.

---

The same reasons apply to the `nosuid` option, which tells the OS to ignore the *setuid* bit which would normally cause a program to be executed with different privileges than those of the user. For example, `/usr/bin/sudo` has the *setuid* bit and is owned by root, so it will always have the same privileges as root does.

Comment: This is a great answer – thanks. If I understand things correctly, another question arises … in the ZEVO support forum: [Why are ZEVO ZFS mounts without the nodev option?](http://zevo.getgreenbytes.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1989) (At the moment I have no spare USB hard disk drive to give to HFS Plus alone.)

Comment: @GrahamPerrin: Such options as `nodev` are disabled by default, and have to be explicitly set when mounting. The OS X removable disk auto-mounter sets them, the equivalent programs on Linux do too, but they will not be set when running `mount` from terminal unless you manually add `-o nodev`. *(This does not hurt security since `mount` itself requires root privileges.)* So it depends on how your ZEVO ZFS disk is mounted.

Comment: With ZEVO Community Edition 1.1.1, import is dynamic (automatic) and it seems that the default is to mount automatically without `nodev`. Neither the import nor the ZFS mount requires authentication … let's see how things fan out in the ZEVO area.

Comment: @grawity : Wrong,`nodev`option tells to reject reads and writes to device files so that existing one are concerned too.  You can still create them.